# About the Point Cloud Coordinate System Issued by the RGB-D Camera

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a strange problem when I used the turbobot3 simulation.Why The point cloud direction published by camera_rgb_optical_frame is upward.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408011/about-the-point-cloud-coordinate-system-issued-by-the-rgb-d-camera/) by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/117137/wugeshenhuaking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are established conventions for the frame's x, y and z-axis for a camera image. Please read this page:

https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html

If you are in a hurry, search for `_optical`.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/117137/wugeshenhuaking/) on 2022-10-17**:
@Mike Scheutzow Does this mean that I must transform the point cloud released by this coordinate system into a common coordinate system under ROS. Then I can do related work, such as filtering too high or too low point clouds. Then transform the processed point cloud inverse coordinates back to _optical frame.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-10-17**:
*Does this mean that I must transform the point cloud released by this coordinate system into a common coordinate system under ROS*

Yes, but it is easy to implement if the camera is in your TF tree: use `tf2_ros Buffer.transform()` to convert each point into the TF frame you want to work in (typically `base_link` or `map`.)

For a robot-mounted camera, your TF usually looks something like `base_link -> camera_base -> camera_optical`. The `camera_optical` origin is at corner of the image sensor inside the camera body.

Typically you won't need to transform the data points back to `camera_optical` frame, but nothing stops you from doing so.